# DataBind a Control to another Control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have two converters, one sets the control visibility to Hidden if the text is null.  The other converts an int into a string.  I'm trying to use them both below, I want to make the DockPanel Hidden if tbDisposition.Text is null, but my DockPanel binding is a bit off.

```
<DockPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=tbDisposition.Text, Converter={StaticResource cIsVisible}}">  
                    <TextBlock Text="Disposition: "/>
                    <TextBlock Name="tbDisposition" Text="{Binding Path=SessionEvent.DispositionID, Converter={BLL:CodeMarkupExtension}}" Foreground="Blue" />
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx):

```
<DockPanel Visibility="{Binding ElementName=tbDisposition, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource cIsVisible}}">  
    <TextBlock Text="Disposition: "/>
    <TextBlock Name="tbDisposition" Text="{Binding Path=SessionEvent.DispositionID, Converter={BLL:CodeMarkupExtension}}" Foreground="Blue" />
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

When binding objects to a `Text` property, `ToString()` is automatically called on that object so there shouldn't be a need for an "int to string" converter. You can just override ToString instead.